# Override default auth options in Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

When you authenticate app this way:

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({
    key: 'key'
});

client.authenticate({
    interactive: false
}, function(error){
    if(error){
        alert('Authentication error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

and then

```
client.authenticate();
```

SDK stores token and others in localStorage, so next time you don't need to redirect user to dropbox oauth page etc. But when you pass them to Dropbox.Client constructor:

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({
    key: 'key',
    token: 'token',
    uid: 'uid'
});
```

these values are not stored in localStorage, so you have to pass them each time you want to construct Dropbox.Client. My question is:

Is it some API in Dropbox Javascript SDK to override default oauth options?

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Why don't you just store them in local storage and then reuse yourself?

Comment: @smarx Yeah, I'm currently doing so, but I'm just looking for some "more official" way to do that. Btw. Are you from Dropbox API team? I'm asking because I probably "saw" you on twitter (Datastore API thread) yesterday :)

Comment: I don't think there's a "more official" way to do it. Yes, I'm a developer advocate at Dropbox.